# How does spark stores the streaming data as if it continues to append the incoming data into the unbounded table the memory will be full?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to spark and have this confusion in streaming of data by spark. When it comes in appending input streams to the unbounded table and when the input data streams are large, how is the memory managed as it is unbounded and for how long the streaming data stays in the table?